# Html not displaying expected data

Tags: html

Does not perform this operation. When you run the code, the program outputs a blank page, and should display Hello, World !. Please correct the error!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html> 
    <head> 
      <base target="_top"> 
    </head> 
    <body> Hello, World! </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: Show your full script

Comment: what does this have to do with Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes around top in  cannot be the "Microsoft specific" quotes.

This: "_top" works

This: “_top” fails

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and past your ***html*** file as it is. There is nothing wrong with your html tags, everything is working fine and up to mark.

After seeing your question I am impatient to know about that how you create your html file?